# How to get the last inserted primary key' s value

Tags: mysql

I have a customer table storing details of all customers. The customer_id is the primary key of customer table. I need to get the value of the recently inserted customer's customer_id.How can I get it? Please help me.What is the syntax for it?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

> It returns a BIGINT (64-bit) value representing the first
>   automatically generated value that was set for an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column by the most recently executed INSERT statement to affect such a
>   column. For example, after inserting a row that generates an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT value, you can get the value like this:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
>         -> 195
> ```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, you can get last inserted id  by using below mentioned two method based on the `mysql` or `mysqli`,

mysqli:

```
 mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

mysql:

```
 mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: hi chinnu..thank you..so much...but I got it already.Thank you for your help